# How to exploit interrupts for data transfer over SPI peripheral

Tags: c, callback, embedded, interrupt, spi

I have been implementing device driver for the SPI peripheral of the MCU in C language.
I would like to exploit interrupt mechanism for reception and also for transmission.

As far as the reception part I think that I can implement this via exposing
the function *SpiRegisterCallback* into the SPI driver interface. This function
enables the client register its function which will be invoked as soon as
data byte is received (reception buffer full interrupt is invoked).

As far as the transmission part I would like to use some *SpiTransmit* function
which will receive pointer to the data bytes to be transmitted and number of bytes
to be transmitted. As far as implementation I am going to define some internal
callback function of the SPI driver. This internal callback will be registered
for transmission buffer empty interrupt. In this callback function the passed data bytes will be gradually placed into the transmission buffer. I am not sure whether this approach
is appropriate. Can anybody give me an advice how to implement SPI peripheral
driver which exploits interrupts for data transmission? Thanks in advance for any 
suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

SPI is often very real-time critical, introducing a callback with function pointers means needless overhead code. The actual copying of data from SPI to RAM must be done internally by your driver. That's all the ISR should be doing. Some general guidance can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/329961/6102).

So your ISR should be filling up a buffer, then *swap pointers to buffers* (no slow `memcpy`!) in a protected way, so that the caller always has one buffer with valid data, and the ISR always has one working buffer to fill up. Let the caller poll a flag rather than to invoke a callback from inside an ISR. I like to use tripple buffering if I can spare the RAM. That is: one buffer for the ISR, one buffer for the caller and one spare that the ISR can swap with without disrupting the caller.

This is all rather intricate to code and most programmers get it wrong. DMA is superior to interrupts here, so you should really be considering DMA instead. This is something you should be considering when picking MCU.

Comment: 'Let the caller poll a flag' .. or' if available/relevant, wait on a semaphore until the interrupt handler signals a full buffer.

Comment: @MartinJames If you have a higher level OS sure. Otherwise in case of bare metal, you'll have to implement the semaphore yourself.

Comment: A ring-buffer or FIFO are possible alternatives to consider over a ping-pong buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A request for "any suggestions" does not really make this a great question because multiple answers may be acceptable, and few will be comprehensive.  It invites comments rather then answers.  However I will indulge:

First, this is not by any definition an exploit.  To "exploit" implies making use of something for a purpose it was not intended - that is not the correct term in this case, you are not "exploiting" the interrupt mechanism, you are simply *using* it.

At high clock rates, in some cases the interrupt latency and context switch time involved in processing the interrupts may be less efficient than a simple busy-wait. If the transfers are more than two or three bytes at a time, you should in any case consider using DMA if available - so the interrupt will be the DMA interrupt for a complete transfer rather then a single character.  For applications such as SD card interfacing or EEPROM, DMA will have a significant performance impact and free up the CPU to do other useful work concurrently.  A driver that uses a busy-wait for single byte/word transfers and DMA for block transfers may be optimal.  This is particularly true perhaps if you are using an RTOS and the ISR triggers a task context to process the data - the context switch overhead may be nearly as much or more than a busy-wait for a single byte.  If your SPI clock is > 1MHz for example, you will wait 8us for a byte transfer, your ISR and call backs could easily be greater then that, in which case it is not worthwhile.

So my advice here is to only consider interrupts for SPI if you are using a slow clock and can get *other* useful work done whilst waiting for the interrupt.

A problem with allowing call-backs in interrupts is it allows the callback provider to do things ill-advised or illegal in an interrupt context, and you loose the ability to control the processing time of the interrupt.   It is fine perhaps if the callback is intended for use by someone writing a device driver - they should be aware of what they are doing, but this *is* the device driver.